# opencv 3D Points to Real Distance measure?

Tags: c++, opencv

I used a stereo camera,

Distortion correction was completed and Disparity was calculated.

Thereafter, xyz coordinates were obtained using "reprojectImageTo3D" function.

.

I want to get the actual distance of the object. inch or mm, cm etc ...

.

What should I do?

```
Mat xyz;

reprojectImageTo3D(disp, xyz, Q, true);

int mousePositionX = 100;
int mousePositionY = 130;
// how convert real distance [mousePositionX ,mousePositionY]
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsozp.png)